# Position Polymer core-drawer-panel drawer panel to the right

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm little confused how to put the drawer panel to the right side of page instead of the left when using Polymer core-drawer-panel.

As described [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html) this should be possible.

`<core-drawer-panel>`

> A responsive container that combines a left- or right-side drawer
>   panel for navigation or other options and a main content area.

The [documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-drawer-panel) for core-drawer-panel shows that there is no position attribute  or something similar to use.

What I'm trying to produce is something like the image below where the drawing panel is on the right.
Example:

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
    <div main>
      ...
    </div>
    <div drawer> <!-- I want to be on the right side -->
      ...
    </div>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`<core-drawer-panel class="right-drawer"></core-drawer-panel>`

This needs to be documented, would you mind filing an issue here: https://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel?

Comment: It now needs to be `<core-drawer-panel rightDrawer></core-drawer-panel>`.

Comment: In Polymer 1.0 it's now actually: `<paper-drawer-panel right-drawer></paper-drawer-panel>`. core-elements have been renamed/moved to other places and `right-drawer` is now the correct attribute.